# Scaling graphics with AffineTransform

Tags: java, swing, affinetransform

I am making a GUI with Swing that uses an AffineTransform to scale Graphics2D objects painted on a JInternalFrame.  The problem is that it is buggy in the current state and I can't figure out why.

Why isn't my code scaling properly?  Why do the graphics "jump" to the top of the panel on a resize?

Here is my self contained example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.*;

public class MainPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private static final double version = 1.0;
    private JDesktopPane desktop;
    public static RFInternalFrame frame;

    private java.util.List<Point> POINT_LIST = Arrays.asList(
            //Top Row
            new Point(50, 30),
            new Point(70, 30),
            new Point(90, 30),
            new Point(110, 30),
            new Point(130, 30),
            new Point(150, 30),
            new Point(170, 30),
            new Point(190, 30),
            new Point(210, 30),
            new Point(230, 30),

            //Circle of Radios
            new Point(140, 60),
            new Point(120, 80),
            new Point(100, 100),
            new Point(100, 120),
            new Point(120, 140),
            new Point(140, 160),
            new Point(160, 140),
            new Point(180, 120),
            new Point(180, 100),
            new Point(160, 80));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new MainPanel();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MainPanel() {
        super("MainPanel " + version);

        //Make the big window be indented 50 pixels from each edge
        //of the screen.
        int inset = 50;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(inset, inset,
                screenSize.width - inset * 7,
                screenSize.height - inset * 4);

        //Set up the GUI.
        desktop = new JDesktopPane(); //a specialized layered pane
        desktop.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        createRFFrame(); //create first RFFrame
        createScenarioFrame(); //create ScenarioFrame

        setContentPane(desktop);
        setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

        //Make dragging a little faster but perhaps uglier.
        desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);
    }

    protected JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //Set up the lone menu.
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        menuBar.add(menu);

        //Set up the first menu item.
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Add Panel");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                KeyEvent.VK_N, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menuItem.setActionCommand("new");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        //Set up the second menu item.
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                KeyEvent.VK_Q, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menuItem.setActionCommand("quit");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        return menuBar;
    }

    //React to menu selections.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("new".equals(e.getActionCommand())) { //new
            createRFFrame();
        } else {
            //quit
            quit();
        }
    }

    /*
     * ActivateAllAction activates all radios on the panel, essentially changes the color
     * of each ellipse from INACTIVE to ACTIVE
     */
    private class ActivateAllAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ActivateAllAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(1);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        /*
         * This will find the selected tab and extract the DrawEllipses instance from it
         * Then for the actionPerformed it will call activateAll() from DrawEllipses
         */
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Component comp = desktop.getSelectedFrame();
            if (comp instanceof DrawEllipses){
                DrawEllipses desktop = (DrawEllipses) comp;
                desktop.activateAll();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * DeactivateAllAction deactivates all radios on the panel, essentially changes the color
     * of each ellipse from ACTIVE to INACTIVE
     */
    private class DeactivateAllAction extends AbstractAction {
        public DeactivateAllAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        /*
         * This will find the selected tab and extract the DrawPanel2 instance from it
         * Then for the actionPerformed it will call activateAll() from DrawEllipses
         */
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Component comp = desktop.getSelectedFrame();
            if (comp instanceof DrawEllipses){
                DrawEllipses desktop = (DrawEllipses) comp;
                desktop.deactivateAll();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Define a JPanel that will hold the activate and deactivate all JButtons
     */
    protected JPanel btnPanel() {
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();

        btnPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredSoftBevelBorder());

        //Set the layout of the frame to a grid bag layout
        btnPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        //Creates constraints variable to hold values to be applied to each aspect of the layout
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        //Column 1
        c.gridx = 0;
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new ActivateAllAction("Activate All")));

        //Column 2
        c.gridx = 1;
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new DeactivateAllAction("Deactivate All")));
        return btnPanel;
    }

    //not used currently
    protected JPanel drawPanel() {
        JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();
        drawPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredSoftBevelBorder());
        DrawEllipses drawEllipses = new DrawEllipses(POINT_LIST);
        drawPanel.add(drawEllipses);

        return drawPanel;

    }

    //Create a new internal frame.
    protected void createRFFrame() {
        RFInternalFrame iframe = new RFInternalFrame();
        iframe.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        DrawEllipses drawEllipses = new DrawEllipses(POINT_LIST);
        iframe.add(drawEllipses);
        iframe.add(btnPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        iframe.setVisible(true);
        desktop.add(iframe);

        try {
            iframe.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
    }

    protected void createScenarioFrame() {
        ScenarioInternalFrame frame = new ScenarioInternalFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.setVisible(true);
        desktop.add(frame);

        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
    }

    //Quit the application.
    protected void quit() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawEllipses extends JPanel {
    private double translateX; //
    private double translateY; //
    protected static double scale; //
    private static final int OVAL_WIDTH = 15;
    private static final Color INACTIVE_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static final Color ACTIVE_COLOR = Color.green;
    private java.util.List<Point> points; //
    private java.util.List<Ellipse2D> ellipses = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<Ellipse2D, Color> ellipseColorMap = new HashMap<>();

    public DrawEllipses(java.util.List<Point> points) {
        this.points = points; //
        translateX = 0; //
        translateY = 0; //
        scale = 1; //
        setOpaque(true); //
        setDoubleBuffered(true); //


        for (Point p : points) {
            int x = p.x - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
            int y = p.y - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
            int w = OVAL_WIDTH;
            int h = OVAL_WIDTH;
            Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
            ellipses.add(ellipse);
            ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, INACTIVE_COLOR);
        }

        MyMouseAdapter mListener = new MyMouseAdapter();
        addMouseListener(mListener);
        addMouseMotionListener(mListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform(); //
        tx.translate(translateX, translateY); //
        tx.scale(scale, scale); //

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setTransform(tx);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
            g2.setColor(ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse));
            g2.fill(ellipse);
        }
    }

    private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
                if (ellipse.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    Color c = ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse);
                    c =  (c == INACTIVE_COLOR) ? ACTIVE_COLOR : INACTIVE_COLOR;
                    ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, c);
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    //Used for button click action to change all ellipses to ACTIVE_COLOR
    public void activateAll(){
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses){
            ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, ACTIVE_COLOR);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    //Used for button click action to change all ellipses to INACTIVE_COLOR
    public void deactivateAll(){
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses){
            ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, INACTIVE_COLOR);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}

class RFInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame implements ComponentListener {
    protected static double scale = 1; //
    static int openFrameCount = 0;
    static final int xOffset = 300, yOffset = 0;

    public RFInternalFrame() {
        super("RF Panel #" + (++openFrameCount),
                true, //resizable
                true, //closable
                true, //maximizable
                true);//iconifiable

        setSize(300, 300);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        addComponentListener(this);

        if (openFrameCount == 1) {

            setLocation(0,0);
        }
        else if (openFrameCount <= 4) {

            //Set the window's location.
            setLocation(xOffset * (openFrameCount - 1), yOffset * (openFrameCount - 1));
        }
        else if (openFrameCount == 5) {

            setLocation(xOffset - 300, yOffset + 300);
        }
        else if (openFrameCount == 6) {

            setLocation(xOffset + 600, yOffset + 300);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        String str = "";
        if (getWidth() < 300) {
            str = "0." + getWidth();
        } else {
            str = "1." + (getWidth() - 300);
            System.out.println(getWidth() - 300);
        }
        double dou = Double.parseDouble(str);
        MainPanel.frame.scale = dou;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent componentEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent componentEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent componentEvent) {

    }
}

class ScenarioInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {
    static int openFrameCount = 0;
    static final int xOffset = 300, yOffset = 300;

    public ScenarioInternalFrame() {
        super("Test Scenario" + (++openFrameCount),
                true, //resizable
                true, //closable
                true, //maximizable
                true);//iconifiable

        //...Create the GUI and put it in the window...

        //...Then set the window size or call pack...
        setSize(600, 300);

        //Set the window's location.
        setLocation(xOffset, yOffset);
    }
}
```

Comment: From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setTransform(java.awt.geom.AffineTransform)) "*WARNING: This method should never be used to apply a new coordinate transform on top of an existing transform because the Graphics2D might already have a transform that is needed for other purposes"*, instead, try using [`Graphics2D#transform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#transform(java.awt.geom.AffineTransform))

Comment: Can't you save it and then set it back? before returning?

Comment: @MadProgrammer so you are saying make a public abstract void transform(AffineTransform Tx) method and then call it from the InternalFrame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it, the Graphics object already contains a transform that does a translate to account for the height of the title bar of the internal frame. When you replace the transform you lose this translation so your code is painted at the top of the frame under the title bar.

1. Don't change properties of the Graphics object passed to the paintComponent() method. Instead create a Graphics2D object you can customize.
2. When you create a new transform you need to apply the existing transform first before adding new transforms.

The basic structure would be something like:

```
super.paintComponent(g);

Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform(); //
tx.concatenate( g2.getTransform() );
tx.scale(...); 
g2.setTransform(tx);

// do custom painting

g2.dispose(); // release Graphics resources
```

This will just help the painting. You still have several problems (which I can't solve):

1. Your scale value is never getting updated. You should be adding the ComponentListener to the DrawEllipse panel. You might want to create a `setScale()` method in the panel that you invoked to set the scale when the panel is resized.
2. Once you do paint the circles scaled, you MouseListener won't work. The location of all the circles will be different because they have been scaled. You might be able to scale each circle as you iterate through the list of circles.

Also, when you have a question post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. You have a simple question about using a transform on a panel. So create a frame with a panel and paint a couple of circles on the panel to test the concept.

All the other code is irrelevant to the problem. The menu items are irrelevant, the second internal frame is irrelevant. The MouseListener clicking code is irrelevant. We don't have time to read through 100's of lines of code to understand the question.

Edit:

I changed the order of the code. The tx.scale(...) method must be invoked before setting the transform to the Graphics object.

Comment: thanks for the help and posting advice.  I will do that for future SSCCE's.

Comment: @feltersnach, Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I haven't solved it yet, I will click accept when it is solved.

Comment: @feltersnach, What isn't solved? Its 2-3 lines of code that need to change. It either works or it doesn't. I tested the code before I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I my experience, painting on Swing will be done with double buffer. Means that you create the drawing buffer (ie. ImageBuffer). you apply all your drawing logic to the Graphics of the drawing buffer, including transformation, and then finally, draw your buffer into the component's graphics.

This is how I solve your problem...

```
class DrawEllipses extends JComponent { // I change from JPanel to JComponent, this might not be necessary though...
...
...
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // create the drawing buffer.
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics big = bi.getGraphics();

    // prepare transform
    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform(); //
    tx.translate(translateX, translateY); //
    tx.scale(scale, scale); //

    // get the buffer graphics and paint the background white.
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) big;
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

    // apply drawing logic to the Graphics of the buffer
    g2.setTransform(tx);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
        g2.setColor(ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse));
        g2.fill(ellipse);
    }

    // finally, draw the buffer to the component graphics.
    g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Try it... hope it works and helps.